# How to get the key value from a JSON Dictionary inside a List using python

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I've created a script that check for keys of a dictionary inside a json. I want to be able to pull data from jira in which I already have from the dictionary. Inside my json I've stumbled across a dictionary inside a List and I can't seem to get the value for it. The keys have a customfield in them and I need all the values in these keys. Below is my code I have working where its only a dictionary. Please help me with the List that stores the key, value in a dictionary. The code below checks the keys and if they exist it gets added to the list.

```
keyReporter = ""
listAllIssues = []

def iterateDictIssues(oIssues, listInner):
        for key, values in oIssues.items():        
            if(key == "fields"):
                fieldsDict = dict(values)
                iterateDictIssues(fieldsDict, listInner)    
            elif(key == "issuetype"):
                issuetypeDict = dict(values)
                iterateDictIssues(issuetypeDict, listInner)    
            elif(key == "displayName"):
                keyReporter = values
                listInner.append(keyReporter)

for key, value in dictProjectIssues.items():
        if(key == "issues"):                
            # Get the total number of issues present
            # for our project.
            totalIssues = len(value)    
            for eachIssue in range(totalIssues):    
                listInner = []
                iterateDictIssues(value[eachIssue], listInner)
                listAllIssues.append(listInner)
```

The JSON I have below is the dictionary that I have working from the code above.

```
"issuetype": {
             "self":"https://jira.com"
             "id":"11200",
             "description":"",
             "name":"Requirement",
             "subtask":false,
             }
```

JSON data below to get the value in which I need help.

```
"customfield_12951": [
               {
                  "self":"https://www.jira.com",
                  "value":"Inspection",
                  "id":"12375",
                  "disabled":false
               }
            ]
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to find the keys of the dictionary inside `customfield_12951` list?

Comment: if you have `list` then you have to use `for`-loop to work with every element on `list`.

Comment: without example data we have no idea what is your problem and we can't help you.

Comment: The code I uploaded is all the code that I have that is working. Only code I didn't upload is sending the request and loading it into a json, which isn't important. And yes, I want to find the keys of the dictionary inside of customfield_12951. I specifically said that in the description.

Comment: the code i have already finds the values from the dictionary from the first json I have above. My confusion is the second json I have, which has the list and inside the list is a dictionary. I'm trying to see if I can take my same approach that is looping through the dictionary and also loop through the List and add those same values to the List.